# Laravel Eloquent model not updating

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a Tag model with two fields; the `tag` and the `tag_type.` I am trying to update the `tag_type,` but it doesn't seem to save on the update.

```
$tag->tag_type = $request->tag_type;
$tag->save();

dd($tag, Tag::where('tag', $tag->tag)->first());
```

I updated the `tag_type` and saved it. When I dump it, the updated tag model shows the `tag_type` has been updated. But when I re-query and dump it, the tag type has not changed. Am I missing a step in the update?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `tag_type` to the `$fillable` property in your model.

```php
protected $fillable = ['tag_type'];
```

Or try defining the `$guarded` property as an empty array.

```
protected $guarded = [];
```